# Create zip file with password protection in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nautilus, password, 18.04, zip

When creating a zip file with password protection in Ubuntu 16.04, using the Nautilus context menu, I was asked for zip options like password protection.

Under Ubuntu 18.04 there seems to be no way to select any zip options. Therefore it is not possible to create a zip file with password protection using the Nautilus context menu.

Workarround: creating the zip file with shell command

```
zip -P pass123 zipfile.zip folder2zip/
```

Any ideas to create the password protected zip-file from Nautilus?

Comment: You may be interested in changing file-manager to full-feature one such as Caja (`sudo apt install caja`). See [my Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/1037303/66509) for details.

Comment: There was an option to encrypt on 16.04 via GUI, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 13):

To create an encrypted zip file in Ubuntu 18.04, open up "Archive Manager" (`file-roller`), click on the top menu (labelled "Archive Manager"), and select "New Archive". Designate the name and destination for your new archive, and change to extension to `.zip`. Under the "Other Options" sub-menu, create a password, thereby encrypting the archive. Click "Create", then drag or select the specified files into place, and you're done.

Comment: Are you sure that you are talking about Ubuntu 18.04. The way you describe was the way under Ubuntu 16.04. Under Ubuntu 18.04 I cannot find any "Other Options" submenu (neither as button nor as contect menu).

Comment: It works in 18.04 for me. What version of `file-roller` do you have installed? Are you running the Gnome 3 desktop? Unfortunately, my rather unspectacular answer doesn't give a nautilus-based solution, but the user interface of Archive Manager is pretty straightforward and should do well as another workaround.

Comment: You are right, using `file-roller` (`Archivverwaltung` in german language version) is a workaround to create a password protected zip file without shell. Thanks for this useful hint.

Comment: //,  Works on 18.10

Comment: It's there a way to use this as the dialog when you right click files -> compress in nautilus?

Answer (score 6):

After compressing the files into a zip format.

1. Open it and click on the three stacks on the right.
2. Tap on password and you can set any password for the zip file.

JOB DONE

Remember,to change password again,

1. Go to the password tab and type the new password
2. Click enter again a window will appear asking password.
3. Type in the old password and click `ok` to change the password of the archive.

Comment: working for version 18.04

Comment: tnx you a lot, such method is much faster and comfortable

Comment: A really comfortable approach! +1

Comment: Glad to be of help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this video [How to password zip files in Ubuntu 17.10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wpmfcVtkjA), although this is made for `ubuntu 17.10` this approach also works with `ubuntu 18.04`