# How to create password protected archive in Caja file-manager?

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, 18.04, archive, caja

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Previously in 16.04 LTS I used Nautilus for such action.

How can I create password protected archive using Caja file-manager here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create password protected archive in Caja file-manager one should:

1. Open Caja file manager
2. Make right click on the folder to arhive

   [image: selecting Compress action in Caja]
3. New window named *Compress* will open

   [image: Compress window]
4. Click on *Other Options* and select password capable archive type in the right part of *Filename* (such as default *.zip*, *.7z*, *.cbz*, *.ear*, *.exe*, *.war*) then enter password in *Password* field and click *Create*

   [image: specifying the password]
5. The password protected archive is created.

**Note:** if Caja and its archiving functionality are not installed -
one can install them with `sudo apt install caja engrampa`. Here Engrampa is archive manager for MATE desktop (an analog for file-roller in GNOME).