# No "other options" menu in Archive Manager

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, archive, compression, file-roller

I'm on 20.04 and I'm trying to password protect a compressed file with Archive Manager and was told that there should be an "Other Options" menu at the bottom to set a password. But when I compress the file, I don't see it:

[image]

Can someone explain why I don't see it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create password protected archive in Caja file-manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037303/how-to-create-password-protected-archive-in-caja-file-manager) . It is time to say good bye for Nautilus and GNOMEs Hell, remove them (if you are ready - [here is how](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233026/66509)) . Install Caja (or full MATE) and use this essential functionality as it was before).

Comment: Try selecting **.7z**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right-click option "Archive" in nautilus file manager does not support creating a password protected archive anymore. Probably to keep things minimal and to the bare essentials, but one could indeed argue that this might not have been the best decision in this case.

To create password protected archives, you will need to launch Fileroller separately. It is installed by default on Ubuntu. You cannot by default do so anymore from the nautilus right-click menu indeed.

Answer (score 3):

### How to Make an Encrypted File / Directory with 7Zip

- Install `p7zip-full` from the Universe repository. Using a terminal you can run:

  ```
  sudo apt install p7zip-full
  ```
- <kbd>Right-click</kbd> a file or folder and select *Compress*.
- Confirm the archive name and select *.7z*, then *Create*.
- <kbd>Right-click</kbd> the `.7z` archive and select *Open with Archive Manager*.
- Select the three lines icon <kbd>☰</kbd> on the upper right and click *Password...* to create an AES-256 encrypted archive.

**Notes**

- You will need to install 7-Zip to open the archive on a Windows machine.
- Selecting and remembering a strong password is an important part of encryption security. There are many good articles about this topic on the internet.
- HDDs, SSDs and flash drives can all brick without notice. SLC, (Single Level Cell) SSDs and flash drives have the longest life spans. It is a good idea to keep a backup drive and s copy of the password in your safety deposit box.
- A full tutorial on P7Zip-Desktop can be found at: https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-p7zip-gui-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/