# Nautilus script that creates a password protected ZIP

Tags: bash, nautilus, nautilus-script

In the latest versions of ubuntu, right clicking on a file doesn't give you the possibility to create password protected archives [(see this question)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037290/create-zip-file-with-password-protection-in-ubuntu-18-04). I still need to do that kind of things though so I was trying to create a nautilus script that does the same job.

It's still very raw (I'm not very good with bash scripting) but it sort of works. The only problem is: it breaks if there is a space in a file name.

```
#!/bin/bash
files=""
for line in $@; do
    files+=" $line"
done

cd $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI
gnome-terminal -t "Compressing File(s)" --hide-menubar -e "zip -r --encrypt compressed_file.zip $files"
```

How can I wrap the `$line` variable (line 4) to wrap the filename inside quotes?

edit: I could use file-roller instead of the shell zip command (it's even simpler indeed):

```
#!/bin/bash

file-roller -d $@
```

But still, I have to wrap the file names into quotes in order to avoid problems

Comment: FileManager-Actions (previously known as Nautilus-Actions) may help to get ready-to-use solution - see https://askubuntu.com/a/1031746/66509 .

Comment: @N0rbert That answer followed by [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969650/how-to-make-nautilus-use-file-roller-in-17-10-like-in-17-04) should solve this problem then.

Comment: Using nautilus-actions is a way to get around the problem, but if I can solve the quotes thing it wouldn't even be needed: Instead of the `gnome-terminal - t...` application I could launch `file-roller -d $files` and launch file roller instead of a terminal script.
The problem is, without wrapping every file inside quotes, if there is a space in a filename it would be skipped... I'd like to fix that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

file-roller -d "$@"
```

Putting quotes around `$@` makes it handle spaces correctly.