# Add password option to default compress menu - 20.04

Tags: password, archive, extract

when I click the **compress** option on a file or folder, by right clicking on that file and choosing compress, I am presented with a simple menu form that only lets me choose the type of file to convert to: zip, 7zip, tar.xz.
Is it possible to add the option **password** to that simple menu so that I can convert the files protected with a password more quickly (without having to go to the menu and choosing the password option)?
Thanks!

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048780/nautilus-script-that-creates-a-password-protected-zip

Comment: @fedonkadifeli Thanks for the link. I didn't actually understand what was proposed but I followed a couple of links and I'm resigned to forget the right click option...

Answer (score 1):

I created a very basic script to call it as a *Nautilus (File Manager) Action*. You can add this script as an action to your File Manager by using the [***FileManager-Actions Configuration Tool***](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/fma-config-tool.1.html).

Install the *FileManager-Actions Configuration Tool* using:

```
$ sudo apt install filemanager-actions
```

My script uses [zenity](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/zenity.1.html) to display an input form. If `zenity` is not already installed, you can install it using:

```
$ sudo apt install zenity
```

The script is like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if (( $# != 1 )) ; then
  aname=""
else
  aname="$(echo "$1"|sed -e 's/\.[^./]*$//').7z"
fi
answer=$(zenity --forms --title="Create Compressed File" \
 --text="Archive Name: $aname" --add-entry="New Archive Name:" \
 --add-password="Password:" --add-password="Confirm Password:")
case "$?" in
  1) echo "Cancelled" >&2 ; exit 1 ;;
  -1) echo "Error!" >&2 ; exit -1 ;;
  0) IFS="|" read -r newaname pass1 pass2 <<< "$answer" ;;
esac
if [[ "$pass1" != "$pass2" ]] ; then
  echo "Passwords do no match!" >&2
  exit 2
fi
if [[ -z "$pass1" ]] ; then
  echo "No password is given!" >&2
  exit 3
fi
[[ "$newaname" == "" ]] && newaname="$aname"
if [[ -z "$newaname" ]] ; then
  echo "No archive name is given!" >&2
  exit 4
fi

7z -t7z -p"$pass1" a "$newaname" "$@"
```

You can put a copy of it somewhere in your path (and make it executable). I used `compress_with_pass.sh` as the file name for the script.

The script prompts you for the archive file name (if there is a single file to be compressed, it automatically replaces the extension of the file with `.7z`) and the password for the archive.

To add this script as a "File Manager Action" use the **File-Manager Actions Configuration Tool** you installed as I described above and add an action like this (only the fields that are important are shown here):

**Action** tab:

- ✓ Display item in selection context menu
- Context label: `COMPRESS WITH PASSWORD`

**Command** tab:

- Path: `gnome-terminal`
- Parameters: `-- bash -c  "compress_with_pass.sh %F ; read a"`

**Execution** tab:

- Execution mode: Normal
- Change the other fields according to your needs.

After this, you can select one or more files in your File Manager and right click to access the action called: `COMPRESS WITH PASSWORD`.

**Notes**:

- The script can be improved to allow compression for other formats.
- You can use [yad](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/yad.1.html) for more advanced script input/output (GUI).

---

### Update for Ubuntu 20.10

Since the `filemanager-actions` package is no longer available in Ubuntu 20.10, we have to revert to [Nautilus Scripts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto). I modified the above script accordingly and copied the new version below:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto

msg ()
{
  zenity --info --no-wrap --no-markup --text="$*"
}

aname=$(echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | head -1)
if [[ $aname != "" ]] ; then
  aname="$(echo "$aname"|sed -e 's/\.[^./]*$//').7z"
fi
answer=$(zenity --forms --title="Create Compressed File" \
 --text="Archive Name: $aname" --add-entry="New Archive Name:" \
 --add-password="Password:" --add-password="Confirm Password:")
case "$?" in
  1)  msg "Cancelled" ; exit 1 ;;
  -1) msg "Error!"    ; exit -1 ;;
  0)  IFS="|" read -r newaname pass1 pass2 <<< "$answer" ;;
esac
if [[ "$pass1" != "$pass2" ]] ; then
  msg "Passwords do no match!"
  exit 2
fi
if [[ -z "$pass1" ]] ; then
  msg "No password is given!"
  exit 3
fi
[[ "$newaname" == "" ]] && newaname="$aname"
if [[ -z "$newaname" ]] ; then
  msg "No archive name is given!"
  exit 4
fi

tmpfile=$(mktemp)
echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" >"$tmpfile"
out1=$(echo 7z -t7z -p\""$(echo $pass1|sed 's/./*/g')"\" a \""$newaname"\" -i@"$tmpfile")
out2=$(7z -t7z -p"$pass1" a "$newaname" -i@"$tmpfile" 2>&1)

msg "$out1
___
$out2"

rm "$tmpfile"
```

You have to put the script under the directory `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts` with an appropriate name (say `CompressWith_Pass`) and make it executable (`chmod +x ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/CompressWith_Pass`).

After that, the usage is similar: You can select one or more files in your File Manager and right click to access the **Scripts** menu item having **CompressWithPass** as a sub-item.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a password using the archive manager.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that already but didn't formulated my question well enough. I've edited my question.