# How do I modify the context menu in Nautilus or another file manager for Ubuntu 20.04.1?

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, context-menu, nautilus-actions

I've tried to install nautilus-actions using this guide after a few others:

https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/01/install-nautilus-actions-ubuntu-18-04/

At step 2 it says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package filemanager-actions-nautilus-extension
```

Any advice appreciated, I'm willing to try another file manager too.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS the correct package name is [`filemanager-actions`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/filemanager-actions). Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install filemanager-actions
```

Nautilus support is contained in second package named [`nautilus-extension-fma`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/nautilus-extension-fma). You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-extension-fma
```

Comment: `filemanager-actions` is removed in 20.10 and above. See my answer at: https://askubuntu.com/a/1274782/855322

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Thanks. You may already know my position then. With the progressive illness of Nautilus I would recommend to drop GNOME sHell and install MATE with [Caja-Actions](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/caja-actions) to get fully-featured and customized system for real productive daily work.

Comment: I have written an implementation of FMA that works for 21.10 +Nautilus. It retains most of the same semantics of the original but is much lighter. It isn't available as a .deb yet, but here is the Github repos - Nautilus actions has now been archived by the GNOME maintainers and does not work in 22.10+.

A nascent alternative can be found [here][1].


  [1]: https://github.com/bassmanitram/actions-for-nautilus