# Ubuntu 21.04 - How to add a shortcut to open an specific app from the Right Menu Click of the Mouse?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, mouse

how to add a shortcut to open an specific app from the Right Menu Click of the Mouse?

Let's say that I would like to open 7Zip Wine/Windows .exe or even an Ubuntu software directly from my Right Click Menu of the Mouse. There is an easy or relatively easy way to modify the right Click Menu without to install other File Managers in the system?

Comment: Sorry man , it's true, I'm on the latest release of Ubuntu 21.04 with the latest Gnome from the default system....

Comment: Does Nautilus Scripts help? See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273441/add-password-option-to-default-compress-menu-20-04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I customize the context menu in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-do-i-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus)

Comment: Sorry guys I was studing around on it, `Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool` was perfect and per my understanding the evolution of that was `filemanager-actions 3.4-2`. But the problems it's that are Outdates solutions for ubuntu 21.04. In fact just then I did try to configure Filemanager Action before install it, but in Terminal it shows  " too many allert on that ", so before install it maybe better that I think twise before break the real Nautilus.... Have you got experience to install `Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool` on Ubuntu 21.04?

Answer (score 1):

As of Ubuntu 21.04, your options to create custom right-click menu entries are using Nautilus Scripts (easy, using bash), or Nautilus Python extensions (more integrated, but you need to master some Python). See more detail on various possibilities, some outdated, [in another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-do-i-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus/77285#77285).

Comment: Thank you @vanadium, I need to study a bit on that to understand how it works, it's that just a script as per my understanding , so it's not like `Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool` with a giu? Right?

Comment: The "Nautilus actions tool" indeed does not anymore work, unfortunately.