# Where is the "scripts" directory in Nautilus 43?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, nautilus, 22.10

Where do you put the scripts that appear in the context menu when you right click in a folder or on a file in Nautilus?

[image: Right click menu in nautilus for custom scripts]

*(Screenshot from a previous version of Nautilus)*

My scripts used to work just fine in older versions, but no matter where I place them now, my scripts don't seem to be picked up by Nautilus.

Comment: Put them under `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`.

Comment: @FedKad That was it! (I also realized the scripts weren't showing up because they weren't marked as executable  ) Make the comment a full answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally put my scripts under my user directory called `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`. One such sample script is given below:

```
#!/bin/bash
## Variables: (Refer to: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto)
# NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI='file://... current directory'
# NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS='... each file is terminated with \n'
# NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS='file://... each file is terminated with \n'
# NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_WINDOW_GEOMETRY=1920x999+0+0

echo -n "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | sed -z 's/.$//' | xsel -b -i
zenity --info --no-wrap --no-markup \
  --title="File name(s) copied to Clipboard:" \
  --text="$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"
```

You can save the above script as `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/CopyFile_Path` and *make it executable*¹. After that, you can select some files in *Nautilus*, right click and go to the **Scripts** → **CopyFile_Path** menu item.

You can also group your scripts under sub-directories of the `scripts/` directory. They will be displayed as sub-menu items in the right-click menu.

For more details, please look at another of my answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1274782/855322).

---

<sup>¹ Refer to the `man` pages of [xsel](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/xsel.1.html) and [zenity](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/zenity.1.html) commands. If you don't have these commands on your system, you will have to `sudo apt install xsel zenity`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the documentation](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus-python), scripts are loaded from three locations in this order:

1. `$XDG_DATA_HOME/nautilus-python/extensions` (i.e. `~/.local/share/…`)
2. `nautilus_prefix/share/nautilus-python/extensions` (i.e. `~/Development/…`)
3. `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/nautilus-python/extensions` (i.e. `/usr/share/…`)

After copying a Python script, we're asked to restart Nautilus to ensure the locations are read and any new scripts are loaded.

Comment: That seems to be specific to the `nautilus-python` package. Is that included by default in Ubuntu 22.10, or is that something you have to install explicitly?