# Preview Pane on ubuntu (jammy) in Nautilus

Tags: package-management, nautilus, python3, gtk, nautilus-actions

I like the feature in Windows (Preview pane) but I want this feature in Ubuntu (jammy) in Nautilus File Manager too.
If there is any plugin (Kindly share that).

Anything through which I can enable the preview pane let me know.
Otherwise, I have to build a plugin on my own.

I tried to download Nautilus-actions,but error coming

```
Package nautilus-actions is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'nautilus-actions' has no installation candidate
```

I used the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

Let me know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The packages `nautilus-actions` and `filemanager-actions` are obsolete and they are not available after 20.04. See [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nautilus-actions&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=filemanager-actions&searchon=names).

You might want to use [*Nautilus Scripts*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto).

For an example, please see [one of my previous answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/1274782/855322).

---

Having said that, you can install the package [`gnome-sushi`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-sushi&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and use the <kbd>space</kbd> bar to preview most types of files in Nautilus.